# SQL Average time difference hh:mm:ss by type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the time average time difference, and count of tickets from a database similar to below:

```
[TicketId | OpenedDateTime      | ResponseDateTime    | Category  ]
[12345    | 2018-11-11 15:03:02 | 2018-11-11 15:08:19 | Helpdesk  ]
[12346    | 2018-11-11 15:06:00 | 2018-11-11 15:18:26 | Helpdesk  ]
[12347    | 2018-11-11 15:09:58 | 2018-11-11 15:11:11 | Support   ]
[12348    | 2018-11-11 15:11:33 | 2018-11-11 15:28:56 | Headphones]
[12349    | 2018-11-11 15:12:12 | 2018-11-11 15:15:15 | Support   ]
```

Currently, I have a row by row calculation of the time difference between OpenedDateTime and ResponseDateTime.

```
SELECT 
    [OpenedDateTime],
    [ResponseDateTime],
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, [OpenedDateTime], [ResponseDateTime])/3600)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, [OpenedDateTime], [ResponseDateTime])%3600/60)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, [OpenedDateTime], [ResponseDateTime])%60))), 2) as 'TimeDifference'
FROM 
    [dbo].[ticket]
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
[Category   | TotalTickets | AverageResponseTime]
[Helpdesk   | 2            | 00:09:11           ]
[Support    | 2            | 00:02:33           ]
[Headphones | 1            | 00:17:23           ]
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: To answer your question directly related to your own query...   SELECT 
    Category, COUNT(TicketID) As TotalTickets,
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),AVG(DATEDIFF(second, OpenedDateTime, ResponseDateTime))/3600)), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),AVG(DATEDIFF(second, OpenedDateTime, ResponseDateTime))%3600/60)), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(convert(varchar(5),(AVG(DATEDIFF(second, OpenedDateTime, ResponseDateTime))%60))), 2) as AverageResponseTime
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ticket]
    GROUP BY Category

Comment: @Allumearz Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: Other than the error, it's a good answer.

Comment: Ah, I only tested with the data you provided!